# Redux dispatch action takes more time with a big store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have created a simple example that shows that the bigger store you have the more time you need to dispatch an empty action.

Is it really true that dispatch timing depend on store size?

Here is the example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/tarassov/too-big-store/draft/gracious-leakey)

With an empty store when I try to dispatch a simple action like

```
dispatch({ type: "hey" });
```

it takes less than 1ms.

But with a store that contains 100 000 strings it takes about 10 ms. And as matter of fact more strings you have  - more time it takes.

I used to think the dispatch does not depend on store size  but now I have to rethink my approach. If store contains a lot of data it could happen that every dispatch will take seconds.

Does really dispatch timing depend on store size?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3WfB.png)

Here is my code:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const [log, setLog] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
const add = (text: string) => {
  setLog([...log, text]);
};

const loadData = async () => {
  add("loading a lot of data to the redux store");

  const newState = [];
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    newState.push(i.toString());
  }

  dispatch({ type: "project", payload: { project: newState } });
  add(`data loaded: ${i} strings`);
};

const dummy = async () => {
  add("start dummy dispatch");
  const t0 = performance.now();
  dispatch({ type: "hey" });
  const t1 = performance.now();
  add(`Time it takes to run the function: ${t1 - t0} ms`);
};

const clear = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: "project", payload: { project: [] } });
  setLog([]);
};

return (
  <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadData}>Load data</button>
      <button onClick={dummy}>Dispatch empty action</button>
      <button onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
    </div>
    {log.map((l, i) => {
      return <div key={i}>{l}</div>;
    })}
  </>
);
```

store.ts

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import getProjectReducer from "./reducers/project";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  Project: getProjectReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat()
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export default store
```

reducer

```
import { createReducer, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const getProjectReducer = createReducer<{project: Array<any>}>({project: []}, {
  'project': (
    state,
    action: PayloadAction<{
      project: any;
    }>
  ) => {
    const {project} = action.payload
    state.project=project;
    return state;
  },
});

export default getProjectReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is Redux Toolkit's development-build-only check for non-serializable values in actions and state.  Iterating over the contents of the action and state does take time, and so a larger action or state object will take longer to scan.

However, that check does *not* run in production.

As a side note, you really should be using Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` API rather than calling `createReducer` directly, as `createSlice` is simpler to use (and actually calls `createReducer` internally).

Comment: Mark thank you for your reply! It really works fast on production.
Are there any options to disable  this check on development mode?

Comment: Yes, you can do `getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck: false})`.  See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware